# How to set borders to the data to the excel with Python pandas/XLSX writer

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to format the excel sheet with the borders with python pandas, but no luck, can anyone please assist.

I have data like this:

[image]

I want this in this format:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not straightforward, You have to iterate through the dataframe and add the format to each cell.

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_border()
for col_num, col in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    for row_num, value in enumerate(df[col].values):
        worksheet.write(row_num + 1, col_num + 1, value, cell_format)
```

Comment: thanks Ze'ev Ben-Tsvi,it worked perfectly, but I am also working on converting numerical column to text column do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm sure there's an approach to handle this. If you'll ask a new question, and hand us some code and data, I know you'll get an answer If not by me, then by some faster smarter guy out there.